# Reading child elements by attribute name

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm having trouble figuring out how to read multiple child tags where the tag name is the same (like divs) and when I want to read it by attribute.

So my html snippet looks something like this:

```
<div>....</div>
<div>....</div>
<div class = 'iwantthisone'>
    <h4>value</h4>
    <div class ='ilikethistoo'>
        <span>another value</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So in this example, i'm trying to get the contents of h4 and the contents of span for each instance where that div class shows up.

my relevant php looks like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($path);

$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
$char = $body->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('div'); 

    foreach ($char as $c) {
    $test = $c->getAttribute('class');          
        if ((strpos($test,'iwantthisone') !== false) AND strpos($test,'interaction') == false)) {
            $tree = $c->getElementsByTagName('h4');
                $value = $tree->item(0)->nodeValue;        

        }
    }
```

I know this code can find the class, but i'm not quite getting how I tell it to look at the tree underneath it.

Comment: use xpath? `//div[@class='iwantthisone']/span | //div[@class['iwantthisone']/h4`? for xpath 2.0, it's even easier: `//div[...etc..]/(span,h4)`

Answer (score 0):

Xpath example, the class attribute is a token list (it can contain multiple class names) so the match is a little more complex:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<div>....</div>
<div>....</div>
<div class = 'iwantthisone'>
    <h4>value</h4>
    <div class ='ilikethistoo'>
        <span>another value</span>
    </div>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$expression = '//div[
  contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " iwantthisone ") or
  contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " ilikethistoo ")
]';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $node) {
  var_dump($node->localName, $node->getAttribute('class'));
}
```

Output:

```
string(3) "div"
string(12) "iwantthisone"
string(3) "div"
string(12) "ilikethistoo"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to find class names. like this...

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($path);

$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
$char = $body->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('div'); 

foreach ($char as $c) {
    $test = $c->getAttribute('class');          
        if (preg_match('/iwantthisone/i',$test)) {
            $tree = $c->getElementsByTagName('h4');
            $value = $tree->item(0)->nodeValue;        

        }else if(preg_match('/ilikethistoo/i',$test)){
            //do something else...
    }
```